# Are app engine instances CPUs throttled after a while?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using a App Engine task handler, to process a workload (import files to database).
Looking at my Cloud SQL monitoring, I see that after some minutes, the write rate declines (see picture), and my task runs much slower. Does Google throttle the Instance's CPU or might there be other reasons?

[image]

Comment: The Read/Write drop looks very significant. Have you checked the CPU Utilization chart. Maybe as  the records inserted in the database increase, the inserts become slower due to indexes.

Comment: Usually App Engine is not the best option for batch jobs (this seems to be it, although there's not much context). [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) seems better suited for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms

all cores have turbo frequency, although it is not guaranteed.

> All-core turbo frequency: The frequency at which each CPU typically
> runs when all cores in the socket are not idle at the same time.

This post explains how you can monitor your CPU speed https://askubuntu.com/questions/218567/any-way-to-check-the-clock-speed-of-my-processor

You can ssh into the machine and monitor it real-time.

Comment: A VM's guest environment reflects the base clock frequency, regardless of what frequency the VM is actually running at.

Answer (score 1):

Most services including Cloud SQL provide an IOPS quota which is based upon disk size and other factors.

Your screenshot indicates that you have exceeded that READ quota for Cloud SQL. The result is throttling of disk I/O.

When you created the Cloud SQL instance, you selected a very small storage disk. I recommend resizing that disk larger so that normal operations do not exceed the disk IOPS quota for both read and write.